# will httpnotificationchannel.open() return uri and other informations when i run my windows phone apppicatin in an emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Iam developing a windows phone application that makes use of windows phone push notification service. I know that we use will httpnotificationchannel.open() to open a notification channel with mspn. my question is will httpnotificationchannel.open() return uri and other informations when i run my windows phone apppicatin in an emulator? Is it necessary that i run this application in a windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work in the emulator.

It would have also been quicker to try than write your question.